# Derived contract must override function "supportsInterface". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, alchemy

```
TypeError: Derived contract must override function "supportsInterface". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
```

--> royalty.sol:9:1:
|
9 | contract NftMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage,ERC2981 {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721":
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:52:5:
|
52 | function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC2981":
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol:36:5:
|
36 | function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(IERC165, ERC165) returns (bool) {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
---------------code-------------------------------------------------
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract NftMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage,ERC2981 {
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
//_tokenIds variable has the most recent minted tokenId
Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
//Keeps track of the number of items sold on the marketplace
Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;
//owner is the contract address that created the smart contract
address payable owner;
//The fee charged by the marketplace to be allowed to list an NFT
uint256 listPrice = 0.01 ether;

```
//The structure to store info about a listed token
struct ListedToken {
    uint256 tokenId;
    address payable owner;
    address payable seller;
    uint256 price;
    bool currentlyListed;
}

//the event emitted when a token is successfully listed
event TokenListedSuccess(
    uint256 indexed tokenId,
    address owner,
    address seller,
    uint256 price,
    bool currentlyListed
);

//This mapping maps tokenId to token info and is helpful when retrieving details about a tokenId
mapping(uint256 => ListedToken) private idToListedToken;

constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
}

function updateListPrice(uint256 _listPrice) public payable {
    require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can update listing price");
    listPrice = _listPrice;
}

function getListPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    return listPrice;
}

function getLatestIdToListedToken()
    public
    view
    returns (ListedToken memory)
{
    uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
    return idToListedToken[currentTokenId];
}

function getListedTokenForId(
    uint256 tokenId
) public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
    return idToListedToken[tokenId];
}

function getCurrentToken() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _tokenIds.current();
}

//The first time a token is created, it is listed here
function createToken(
    string memory tokenURI,
    uint256 price,
    uint96 feeNumerator
) public payable returns (uint) {
    //Increment the tokenId counter, which is keeping track of the number of minted NFTs
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

    //Mint the NFT with tokenId newTokenId to the address who called createToken
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newTokenId);

    //Map the tokenId to the tokenURI (which is an IPFS URL with the NFT metadata)
    _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);

    //Helper function to update Global variables and emit an event
    createListedToken(newTokenId, price,feeNumerator);

    return newTokenId;
}

function createListedToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price,uint96 feeNumerator) private {
    //Make sure the sender sent enough ETH to pay for listing
    require(msg.value == listPrice, "Have to send ether equal to the listing price");
    //Just sanity check
    require(price > 0, "Make sure the price isn't negative");

    //Update the mapping of tokenId's to Token details, useful for retrieval functions
    idToListedToken[tokenId] = ListedToken(
        tokenId,
        payable(address(this)),
        payable(msg.sender),
        price,
        true
    );
    _setTokenRoyalty(tokenId,msg.sender,feeNumerator);

    _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    //Emit the event for successful transfer. The frontend parses this message and updates the end user
    emit TokenListedSuccess(
        tokenId,
        address(this),
        msg.sender,
        price,
        true
    );
}

//This will return all the NFTs currently listed to be sold on the marketplace
function getAllNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
    uint nftCount = _tokenIds.current();
    ListedToken[] memory tokens = new ListedToken[](nftCount);
    uint currentIndex = 0;
    uint currentId;
    //at the moment currentlyListed is true for all, if it becomes false in the future we will
    //filter out currentlyListed == false over here
    for (uint i = 0; i < nftCount; i++) {
        currentId = i + 1;
        ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
        tokens[currentIndex] = currentItem;
        currentIndex += 1;
    }
    //the array 'tokens' has the list of all NFTs in the marketplace
    return tokens;
}

//Returns all the NFTs that the current user is owner or seller in
function getMyNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
    uint totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
    uint itemCount = 0;
    uint currentIndex = 0;
    uint currentId;
    //Important to get a count of all the NFTs that belong to the user before we can make an array for them
    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (
            idToListedToken[i + 1].owner == msg.sender ||
            idToListedToken[i + 1].seller == msg.sender
        ) {
            itemCount += 1;
        }
    }

    //Once you have the count of relevant NFTs, create an array then store all the NFTs in it
    ListedToken[] memory items = new ListedToken[](itemCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
        if (
            idToListedToken[i + 1].owner == msg.sender ||
            idToListedToken[i + 1].seller == msg.sender
        ) {
            currentId = i + 1;
            ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }
    }
    return items;
}

function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
    uint price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
    address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;
    require(
        msg.value == price,
        "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
    );

    //update the details of the token
    idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
    idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
    _itemsSold.increment();

    //Actually transfer the token to the new owner
    _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
    //approve the marketplace to sell NFTs on your behalf
    approve(address(this), tokenId);
    //fetching royalty info 
    (address recipient, uint256 amount) = royaltyInfo(tokenId, price);
    //transfer royalty amount to the artist
    payable(recipient).transfer(amount);
    //Transfer the listing fee to the marketplace creator
    payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);
    //Transfer the proceeds from the sale to the seller of the NFT
    payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
}

//We might add a resell token function in the future
//In that case, tokens won't be listed by default but users can send a request to actually list a token
//Currently NFTs are listed by default
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just use an OR statement for the return. Here's an example:

```
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721, ERC2981) returns (bool) {
        return (ERC721.supportsInterface(interfaceId) || ERC2981.supportsInterface(interfaceId));
    }
```

Here's a link to OZ forum:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/derived-contract-must-override-function-supportsinterface/6315/10

Comment: I believe the error most likely stems from a **missing override** up the inheritance line.
In the inheritance line, the latest child using `supportInterface()` should first override the function that is being overriden from the parents contracts, and **then** ,as you said, define if the input interface is one of the interfaces to be checked with OR statements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).